# bash - Test if directory contains files ending on .suite

Tags: bash

I'm currently writing a bash script for executing test suites. Besides passing the suites directly to this script, like

```
./bash-specs test.suite
```

it should also be able to execute all scripts in a given directory if no suite is passed to it, like so

```
./bash-specs # executes all tests in the directory, namely test.suite
```

This is implemented like this

```
(($# == 0)) && set -- *.suite
```

So, if no suite is passed, all the files ending on .suite are executed. This works fine but fails if the directory contains no such files.

That means I will also need a check to test if there actually are files with that ending.
How would I do this in bash?

I thought a test like

```
[[ -f *.suite ]]
```

should work but it seems to fail when there are more than one file in the directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `-f` is failing is because `-f` only takes a single parameter. When you do `[[ -f *.suite ]]`, it expands to:

```
[[ -f test.suite test2.suite test3.suite ]]
```

... which is not valid.

Instead, do this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
FILES=`echo *.suite`
if [[ -z $FILES ]]; then 
    echo "No suites found"
    exit
fi

for i in $FILES; do
    # Run your test on file $i
done
```

`nullglob` is a shell option that makes wildcard patterns that aren't found expand to nothing, rather than expanding to the wildcard pattern itself. Once `$FILES` is set to either a list of files or nothing, we can use `-z` to test for emptiness, and display the appropriate error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -al | grep "\.suite";echo $?
```

This will show 0 if file is present and 1 if file is not present

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over every suite file like this:

```
for i in *.suite ; do
    if [ -x $i ] ; then
        echo running $i
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after :

> (($# == 0)) && set -- *.suite

Test if $1 is empty (with -z), then it means that there's no file named *.suite.